# Logstash 1.4.1 multiline codec not working

Tags: multiline, logstash

I'm trying to parse multiline data from log file.
I have tried multiline codec and multiline filter.
but it doesn't work for me.

Log data

```
INFO 2014-06-26 12:34:42,881 [4] [HandleScheduleRequests] Request Entity:
User Name : user
DLR : 04
Text : string
Interface Type : 1
Sender : sdr
DEBUG 2014-06-26 12:34:43,381 [4] [HandleScheduleRequests] Entitis is : 1 System.Exception
```

and this is configuration file

```
input {

   file {
           type => "cs-bulk"
           path =>
           [
                   "/logs/bulk/*.*"
           ]

           start_position => "beginning"
           sincedb_path => "/logstash-1.4.1/bulk.sincedb"

           codec => multiline {
                    pattern => "^%{LEVEL4NET}"
                    what => "previous"
                    negate => true
           }
   }
}

output {

  stdout { codec => rubydebug }

  if [type] == "cs-bulk" {

     elasticsearch {
       host => localhost
       index => "cs-bulk"
     }
   }
}

filter {

  if [type] == "cs-bulk" {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{LEVEL4NET:level} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} %{THREAD:thread} %{LOGGER:method} %{MESSAGE:message}" }
         overwrite => ["message"]
    }
  }
}
```

and this is what I get when logstash parsing the multiline part
It just get the first line, and tag it as multiline.
**the other lines not parsed!**

```
{
    "@timestamp" => "2014-06-27T16:27:21.678Z",
       "message" => "Request Entity:",
      "@version" => "1",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "multiline"
    ],
          "type" => "cs-bulk",
          "host" => "lab",
          "path" => "/logs/bulk/22.log",
         "level" => "INFO",
          "time" => "2014-06-26 12:34:42,881",
        "thread" => "[4]",
        "method" => "[HandleScheduleRequests]"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Place a `(?m)` at the beginning of your grok pattern. That will allow regex to not stop at `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what's going on, but using a multiline filter instead of a codec like this:

```
input {
  stdin {
  }
}

filter {
     multiline {
                    pattern => "^(WARN|DEBUG|ERROR)"
                    what => "previous"
                    negate => true
           }
}
```

Does work in my testing...

```
{
       "message" => "INFO 2014-06-26 12:34:42,881 [4] [HandleScheduleRequests] Request Entity:\nUser Name : user\nDLR : 04\nText : string\nInterface Type : 1\nSender : sdr",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2014-06-27T20:32:05.288Z",
          "host" => "HOSTNAME",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "multiline"
    ]
}
{
       "message" => "DEBUG 2014-06-26 12:34:43,381 [4] [HandleScheduleRequests] Entitis is : 1 System.Exception",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2014-06-27T20:32:05.290Z",
          "host" => "HOSTNAME"
}
```

Except... the test file I used it never prints out the last line (because it's still looking for more to follow)

Comment: I have tried multiline filter

but it doesn't work.

I have removed GROK filter

and it works !

I'm try to figure out how can I make both filters working together

Comment: I believe the problem you are having now is that the multi-line input is no longer matched by grok because grok doesn't deal well with newlines.  I saw a suggestion on another q/a that suggests using `gsub` to replace the `\n` with a space prior to doing the grok.

Comment: Hi @Alcanzar, how can i make the multiline codec to capture the last line also?